# Braintree v.zero sdk v3.5.0 for iOS - How to Save a Card

Tags: ios, objective-c, braintree

I am trying to use the latest (v3.5.0 as of Dec. 2014) Braintree (BT) iOS sdk in my app. I was able to get a client token from my server and present BT's Drop In viewController:

```
Braintree *braintree = [Braintree braintreeWithClientToken:self.clientToken];
BTDropInViewController *dropInViewController = [braintree dropInViewControllerWithDelegate:self];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dropInViewController animated:YES];
```

and BT generates a nonce, which I could capture in a BT delegate method and send to my server for transaction.

The problem I am trying to solve is that since users of my app make payments frequently, I have to save their cards info in the app so they make their next payments by just selecting one of their saved cards; otherwise they will have to enter their card info every time they make a payment. Basically, I just couldn't figure out how BT is getting the saved payment cards list as shown in the right image here:

https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios#braintree-vzero-sdk-for-ios

Any pointer to what I need to do (or sample code) to save card info for future one-touch-payment? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to go about this:

1. Embed the `customer_id` in your [client token](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+ruby/sdk/overview/generate-client-token). In ruby, it will look like this:

   @client_token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate(
     :customer_id => a_customer_id
   )

This change will only impact Drop In. Manually tokenized cards still need to be saved in the Vault explicitly.

2. Alternatively, use the nonce you are currently receiving to [save the payment method in the vault](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+ruby/sdk/server/payment-method-management/create). In ruby, it will look like this:

   result = Braintree::PaymentMethod.create(
     :customer_id => "YOUR_CUSTOMER_ID",
     :payment_method_nonce => "NONCE-FROM-CLIENT"
   )

In both cases, you can [create transactions from the vault](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+ruby/sdk/server/transaction-processing/create-from-vault) using the token (the nonce is no longer needed).